# Xcode Passing NSMutableArray from one class to another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I know this question has been asked countless of times. But none of them seems to be working! Please help! I am unable to pass arrays from one class to another. Blow are my codes

firstClass has an array declared

```
#FirstClass.h

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[testArray addObject:@"test"];
[testArray addObject:@"test2"];
[testArray addObject:@"test3"];

//method to pass array

TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
tvc.getData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tvc.getData = testArray;

NSLog(@"%i", [tvc.getData count]); // returns a value n
```

**Here i get count of 3**

```
}

TableViewController.h

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"%i", [getData count]); // returns a value n
```

**Here i get 0**

```
//Set the title
self.navigationItem.title = @"Countries";
}
```

I tried

```
FirstClass *fc = [[FirstClass alloc] init];
getData = fc.testArray;
```

Doesn't work as well. I tried writing a method and calling the method from my second class.
Ended up with `@interface` error.
Sorry, this is my first time on objective c. Am java educated.
Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second problem, why the `fc.testArray` does not work is that `viewDidLoad` is called only after the `view` property is called. (lazy initialization)

So it works if you do like

```
FirstClass *fc = [[FirstClass alloc] init];
fc.view;
getData = fc.testArray;
```

Comment: dude thanks!!  Ok another question. I ma using a JSON to populate my array in my FirstClass from another method. Thus I am declaring my arrays in that method instead of viewOnLoad. So... how do I solve this?

Comment: How about just calling that method: FirstClass *fc = [[FirstClass alloc] init]; getData = [fc anotherMethod];

Comment: thx for your help. mind taking a look at my codes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027336/xcode-passing-nsmutablearray-from-different-classes this is how I am working with my class