# XCode Passing NSMutableArray from Different Classes

Tags: xcode, arrays

I have 2 classes. A and B. Inside ClassA I have a method which retrieve JSON data and adds into an array. I want to access this array from ClassB. How can I achieve it?

```
ClassA.h
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//initialise arrayPlaces and arrayWeather
[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                    serverURL];
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                    withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

//parse out the json data
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tempArray = [NSJSONSerialization 
             JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
             options:kNilOptions 
             error:&error];

//declare arrayPlaces
arrayToPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//...codes to add array here using a loop...
[arrayToPass addObject:tempString];
}
```

In ClassB, I have a tableView which i want to get all the array from ClassA. How can I achieve this?

```
ClassA *cA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
ClassA.view;
arrayReceived = ClassA.arrayToPass;
```

The above doesn't seem to work when implemented in ClassB.

```
ClassB *cB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[cB setArrayReceived:arrayToPass];
```

Neither does this work when implemented in ClassA after this portion of the code.
"//...codes to add array here using a loop...
[arrayToPass addObject:tempString];

Please help!! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with a singleton form class A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because `fetchData:` is done asynchronously and `arrayToPass` is still not populated when the code `arrayReceived = ClassA.arrayToPass;` runs.

So we have to let `ClassB` know about that. 
How about first declaring a protocol `ClassADelegate` between `ClassA` and `ClassB`, and declare a property in `ClassA` that of type `ClassADelegate` like this:

```
in ClassA.h
@protocol ClassADelegate ;//Forward declaration of the protocol
@interface ClassA {...
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ClassADelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject> 
-(void) classADidReceiveData:(NSArray *)array;
@end
```

then make `ClassB` a delegate of this

```
@interface ClassB : <ClassADelegate> { ...
```

and of course implement the method `classADidReceiveData:` in ClassB:

```
-(void)classADidReceiveData:(NSArray*) array{
 arrayReceived = array;
}
```

Then modify `fetchData:` like:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

...
//...codes to add array here using a loop...
[arrayToPass addObject:tempString];

 //Call the delegate method if a delegate has been set
if(delegate){
     [delegate classADidReceiveData:arrayToPass]
}
}
```

So that when `ClassA` received data, it can make `ClassB` noticed about that.

The overall usage is:

```
ClassA *cA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
cA.delegate = self;
cA.view;
```

If you have something to be done after fetching data in `ClassB`, then do it in `classADidReceiveData` in `ClassB`.

```
-(void)classADidReceiveData:(NSArray *)array{
 arrayReceived = array;
 //Do whatever you want after receiving array
}
```

Comment: Im having a expected identifier error at this line. on class A.h

-(void) classADidReceiveData:(NSArray *array);

Comment: I'm also having an unknown type name at @property (nonatomic, assign) ClassADelegate *delegate;

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer. For expected identifier, change protocol 'ClassADelegate' to protocol 'ClassADelegate <NSObject>' and for unknown type name, change property (nonatomic, assign) 'ClassADelegate *delegate;' to property (nonatomic, assign) 'id<ClassADelegate> delegate;'. I'm now working on android and confused with Java interface :-/

Comment: Thanks! `@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject> -(void) classADidReceiveData:(NSArray* array); @end` still have the expected identifier error. Thanks! Anyway im form android coming to xcode. Usage is so different.

Comment: cA.delegate = self; what does this line do?
anyway `-(void) classADidReceiveData:(NSMutableArray *)array;`
shoudl be this right?

Comment: After making the changes, my application is finally working! Thanks dude! You're a great help! :)

Comment: It's nice to here it helps.  Anyway, I'm sorry for the expected identifier error. cA.delegate = self; assigns a ClassB instance to the ClassA's delegate property, so that in fetchedData: ClassA's instance can call ClassB's classADidRecieveData: impelmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make the array of class A as a `property` of class A then you can easily access it in class B.

```
in Class A.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tempArray;

in Class A.m

@synthesize tempArray;
```

then get the instance of class A in class B and you can access `tempArray` as `class_a_object.tempArray`

Comment: ClassA *cA = [[ClassA alloc]init];
ClassA.view;
arrayReceived = ClassA.arrayToPass;
Isn't this what i have done?

Comment: if you alloc class A in class b then you will always get an empty array, you need to get the same instance of class a that is currently in memory.

Comment: oh.. so how do i get the same instance?

Comment: tell me how r u going from class A to B

Comment: I only link them at the storyboards. When i go to next view. Thats who it's called

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to have the array in class A be declared as a member variable.  And class A needs a method that returns it (could use @synthesize if it is an @property).

Now, you have choices.  Class B could have an A instance as a member: then it just asks A for the array (pointer).  Class B could be instantiated by someone who passes the array to both A and B.   Or the method in A that needs access to B's array could be called by someone who has B as a member and therefore has access to B's array.

There may be more choices yet.

Answer (score 0):

Take an array in app delegate.Declare the Property and synthesize in the app delegate.And then  when you are in the class A,then do like this

Write this code in the class A

```
Appdelegate *app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.somearray = self.yourarray;
```

In classB you can do like this.

```
Appdelegate *app =(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"arr is %@",app.somearray);
```

Comment: Still cannot seem to get it work... My classA is providing the array, thus im calling my ClassA by ClassA *cA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    cA.view;
is this correct?